# $\mathsf{NP}$ complete version of Skolem arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, integer-programming

Definable subsets of $\mathbb N$ in the language of [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) are exactly the eventually periodic sets and quantifier free part corresponds to Integer Programming with linear inequalities.

Linear integer programming is $\mathsf{NP}$ complete since $\mathsf{SAT}$ reduces to it.

Would there be programming constructs that with 'decidable portions of Skolem' leads to $\mathsf{NP}$ completeness?

My background is not logic and not sure if I make sense however if there is reasonable way to salvage the post it will be nice.

I am trying to see if linear integer programming that is $\mathsf{NP}$ complete has an analogy in [Skolem arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_arithmetic) where variable addition is disallowed?

---

$\exists z_1,\dots,z_n\in\mathbb Z: Ax\leq b$ where $A\in\mathbb Z^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb Z^m$ should be translatable to

$$\Big(\prod_{i=1}^nz_i^{a_{i1}}|p_1^b\Big)\wedge\dots\wedge\Big(\prod_{i=1}^nz_i^{a_{im}}|p_m^b\Big)$$

where $p_j$ are primes according to [What are the definable sets in Skolem arithmetic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316546/what-are-the-definable-sets-in-skolem-arithmetic) but $p_j$ are primes and so I am making a mistake.

Comment: I read this but couldn't understand it. The main question has quote marks around "decidable portions of Skolem", and I don't know what that phrase means. I also don't know why $p_j$ being primes indicates a mistake.